# Clickonce Weird Exception

Tags: exception, deployment, clickonce

I'm trying to publish an application via click once and I'm having this weird exception. I searched for information but doesn't find any relevant.

Does anybody does what can be happening? Do you need any other informatio?

Thank you.

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.1
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://www.domain.com/app/Atomic.Theseus.application
                        Server      : Apache/2.0.54
    Application url         : http://www.domain.com/app/Application%20Files/Atomic.Theseus_1_2_0_3/Atomic.Theseus.exe.manifest
                        Server      : Apache/2.0.54

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Atomic.Theseus.application, Version=1.2.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
    Application Identity        : Atomic.Theseus.exe, Version=1.2.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Online only application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://www.domain.com/app/Atomic.Theseus.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
    * The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:32 PM] : Activation of http://www.domain.com/app/Atomic.Theseus.application has started.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Installation of the application has started.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Processing of application manifest has successfully completed.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Found compatible runtime version 2.0.50727.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil using Sentinel.v3.5Client, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil using WindowsBase, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Detecting dependent assembly System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil using System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=msil.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:33 PM] : Request of trust and detection of platform is complete.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [6/20/2010 3:44:34 PM] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Just a comment. This exception occurs on my machine and on any other machine I'm trying to exectute the app.

Then, When I sign the app with a test certificate it works on my machine, but only on mine one.

Answer (score 3):

Are you publishing your application with Visual Studio? Are you making any changes to it after you publish it? This error usually occurs when you have mixed references (>1 reference to different versions of the same dll) or you have circular references. You might also check your main project -- go to properties, click on the Application tab, and down at the bottom under "Icon and Manifest", make sure 'manifest' says "Create application without a manifest".

Comment: Problem Solved. But thanks Robin. Actually, it was a matter of drivers of an scanner I'm using within the app. Once installed on clients PCs, problem dissappear